# Ljung-box test on weekly percentage of total quarter bookings

Tags: time-series, forecasting, forecast, arima

I have a data on the *weekly percentage* of the *total quarter bookings.* The data looks as follows (note: weekly percentages add up to 100 for each quarter) :
[image]
(not real data)

I used the Ljung-box test to see if the data resemble random data. The Ljung-box test give me a very high p-value (0.7), indicating that the data resembles complete random data.

However if I use the actual numbers of the weekly bookings (not percentage of total quarterly), I get a fairly low p-value in the Ljung-box test, indicating that the data is not random.

**Question:** Is this expected when using *percentages of the total*? If so, why?